# WebViewClient loads previous user data even after logout

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I'm loading an URL into my WebView using:

```
mWebView.setWebviewClient(new WebViewClient);
```

This URL loads a Http authentication page. Once a user logs in, his credentials are saved in a `SharedPreference`. Further I have implemented the logout functionality where the I clear all the data.

Again when I try to load the url, it does not show the login page and it automatically signs in with the previous credentials. If I load the URL in a normal browser, the login page loads fine. Only when I apply the `WebViewClient` I get the above behaviour.

Here is my code:-

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Details1.this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
        WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Details1.this).clearUsernamePassword();
        WebViewDatabase.getInstance(Details1.this).clearFormData();


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())
```

I'm very confused and have searched online for an answer but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I spent too much time with this. None of the methods work, as mentioned here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22272.

Finally I solved it by setting flag *wasLoggegIn* in *onReceivedHttpAuthRequest*, and then when I want to clear login credentials, check the flag:

```
if (wasLoggedIn) {
  Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
  i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  finish();
  try {startActivity(i);}
  catch (java.lang.Exception ignore) {}
  System.exit(0);
}
```

So yeah, restart the app. It's the only way, at least on 4.4.2.